# setTimeout() is not working as it should be

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, scroll, settimeout

I need to be able to wait certain amount of time when the scroll event occurs.

**Code:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
    {
       setTimeout(function (){}, 1000); //I need to be able to wait 1 second and then continue with execution...
       $(".loader").show().delay(700).fadeOut();
       $.ajax({ ///more code });
    }
});
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Why the `setTimeout()` doesn't work in this particular example?

Comment: It's working exactly as it should. Your code isn't coded correctly if you were hoping to delay execution. Consider that you're passing a function. Certainly there must be some reason for this.

Comment: yes you are right...I didn't realize this and it was right in front of me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) is non-blocking. Move the code that should happen later into that empty function.

```
setTimeout(function (){
    $(".loader").show().delay(700).fadeOut();
    $.ajax({ /* more code */ });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: ahh stupid me :) it was right in front of me :) thank you though

Answer (score 0):

What you want to delay should be placed inside setTimeout like this -

```
setTimeout(function (){
       $(".loader").show().delay(700).fadeOut();
       $.ajax({ ///more code });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code that needs to wait with in set time out function.

```
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
  if(your condition) 
  {
   setTimeout(function (){
            $(".loader").show().delay(700).fadeOut();
            $.ajax({ ///more code });
            }, 1000);
   }
});
```